# What is the best development estimate template you've found?

Tags: templates, documentation, administration, estimation

I've been putting a fair number of estimates together lately and I'd like to see if I can get a more thorough and - to be honest - better presented estimate document.

Do you have a template that you use regularly that's available online or is there particular content or presentation that you believe is important to include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind.  I've gone and written my own.  Hopefully I'll get feedback on how it might best be improved.

[Excel Software Estimate Template](http://bit.ly/e1iIw3)